# Skipping the last cell with the variable in my table and I can figure out why

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 userforms. One does the search parameters (Search_Button) and the second shows the results (Results) and also loops through the rest of the code and showing the results of the same search parameters (if there is more than 1). It will do 2 but I cannot figure out why it won't do 3+.

I have tried changing the placement of If and End If and else's but I'm unsure what to do. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Search code:

```
Private Sub Clear_Button_Click()
    
    Dim cell        As Range
    
    i = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Loop through each cell in the ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("Table1")
        
        'Cells.FindNext(after:=ActiveCell).Select
        
        'Check for a specific fill color
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            
            'Remove Fill Color
            cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            'Cells.FindNext(after:=ActiveCell).Select
            
        End If
        
    Next cell
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("Database.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Workbooks("Database").Close
    Unload Search_Button
    
End Sub

Private Sub Open_Database_Button_Click()
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\nathan.slatton\Desktop\Database"
    Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
    
End Sub

Private Sub Search_Button_Button_click()
    
    Dim Variable    As Variant
    Dim LineItem    As Variant
    Dim DeptID      As Variant
    Dim Fund        As Variant
    Dim ProjID      As Variant
    Dim Equip       As Variant
    Dim IMEI        As Variant
    Dim Pin         As Variant
    Dim Device      As Variant
    Dim Ordered     As Variant
    Dim Upgraded    As Variant
    Dim Name        As Variant
    Dim EMail       As Variant
    Dim Password    As Variant
    
    If Wireless_Radial_Search.value = True Then Sheets("WTest").Activate Else Wireless_Radial_Search.value = False
    If Landline_Radial_Search.value = True Then Sheets("LTest").Activate Else Landline_Radial_Search.value = False
    If Extension_Radial_Search.value = True Then Sheets("ETest").Activate Else Extension_Radial_Search.value = False
    
    'Find what table matches the radial(Option Button)
    
    Table1 = Sheets("Wtest").ListObjects(1).Name
    Table2 = Sheets("Ltest").ListObjects(1).Name
    Table3 = Sheets("Etest").ListObjects(1).Name
    
    If Wireless_Radial_Search.value = True Then i = Table1
    If Landline_Radial_Search.value = True Then i = Table2
    If Extension_Radial_Search.value = True Then i = Table3
    
    'Make Variable a Variable
    
    Variable = Search_Variable.value
    
    'Clear old results if its there
    
    Range("P1:AC40").Clear
    
    If Wireless_Radial_Search.value = False And Landline_Radial_Search.value = False And Extension_Radial_Search.value = False Then
        MsgBox "Select a Phone Type"
        
        Search_Button.Hide
        Search_Button.Show
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    If Search_Variable.value = "" Then
        
        MsgBox "Please enter search criteria"
        
        Search_Button.Hide
        Search_Button.Show
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    'Find what they are looking for and select the cell
    
    Cells.Find(what:=Search_Variable.value).Select
    'ActiveCell.Copy
    'Range("P40").PasteSpecial
    'Range("P40").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    'Cells.Find(what:=Search_Variable.value).Select
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    'After finding the cell now select the entire row of the table and copy the information
    
    Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(i).DataBodyRange).Copy
    
    'Paste the copied row into P2
    
    Range("P2").PasteSpecial
    
    ' End If
    
    'Hide Search Userform
    
    'Unload Me
    
    'Set the results of the search for the "results" userform as variables
    
    LineItem = Range("p2").value
    DeptID = Range("q2").value
    Fund = Range("r2").value
    ProjID = Range("s2").value
    Equip = Range("t2").value
    IMEI = Range("u2").value
    Pin = Range("v2").value
    Device = Range("w2").value
    Ordered = Range("x2").value
    Upgraded = Range("y2").value
    Name = Range("z2").value
    EMail = Range("aa2").value
    Password = Range("ab2").value
    
    Range("P1:AC2").Clear
    
    'Open Results Userform and show the results of the search
    
    Results.TextBox14 = Search_Variable.value
    
    Results.Textbox1 = LineItem
    Results.TextBox2 = DeptID
    Results.TextBox3 = Fund
    Results.TextBox4 = ProjID
    Results.TextBox5 = Equip
    Results.TextBox6 = IMEI
    Results.TextBox7 = Pin
    Results.TextBox8 = Device
    Results.TextBox9 = Ordered
    Results.TextBox10 = Upgraded
    Results.TextBox11 = Name
    Results.TextBox12 = EMail
    Results.TextBox13 = Password
    
    Search_Button.Hide
    Results.Show
    
    'Go back to the Monthly Billing All sheet
    
    Sheets("Monthly Billing All").Activate
    
End Sub
```

And my results code:

```
Private Sub Results_clear_button_Click()
    
    'Clear all the black fill
    
    Dim cell        As Range
    
    'i = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Loop through each cell in the ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        
        'Cells.FindNext(after:=ActiveCell).Select
        
        'Check for a specific fill color
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            
            'Remove Fill Color
            cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            'Cells.FindNext(after:=ActiveCell).Select
            
        End If
        
    Next cell
    
    'Clear results on close
    
    Range("P2:AC40").Clear
    
    Unload Results
    
End Sub

Private Sub Next_button_Click()
    
    Dim Variable    As Variant
    Dim LineItem    As Variant
    Dim DeptID      As Variant
    Dim Fund        As Variant
    Dim ProjID      As Variant
    Dim Equip       As Variant
    Dim IMEI        As Variant
    Dim Pin         As Variant
    Dim Device      As Variant
    Dim Ordered     As Variant
    Dim Upgraded    As Variant
    Dim Name        As Variant
    Dim EMail       As Variant
    Dim Password    As Variant
    Dim c           As Range
    
    i = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    
    Unload Results
    
    For Each Variable In Range(i)
        
        Cells.FindNext(after:=Variable).Select
        
        If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            
            Cells.FindNext(after:=Variable).Select
            
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            
            Range("P1:AC2").Clear
            Unload Results
            Search_Button.Show
            
        ElseIf Not ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            
            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            
            Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion).Copy
            
            Range("P2").PasteSpecial
            
            LineItem = Range("p2").value
            DeptID = Range("q2").value
            Fund = Range("r2").value
            ProjID = Range("s2").value
            Equip = Range("t2").value
            IMEI = Range("u2").value
            Pin = Range("v2").value
            Device = Range("w2").value
            Ordered = Range("x2").value
            Upgraded = Range("y2").value
            Name = Range("z2").value
            EMail = Range("aa2").value
            Password = Range("ab2").value
            
            Range("P1:AC2").Clear
            
            Results.TextBox14 = Variable
            
            Results.Textbox1 = LineItem
            Results.TextBox2 = DeptID
            Results.TextBox3 = Fund
            Results.TextBox4 = ProjID
            Results.TextBox5 = Equip
            Results.TextBox6 = IMEI
            Results.TextBox7 = Pin
            Results.TextBox8 = Device
            Results.TextBox9 = Ordered
            Results.TextBox10 = Upgraded
            Results.TextBox11 = Name
            Results.TextBox12 = EMail
            Results.TextBox13 = Password
            
            Results.Show
            
        Else: Search_Button.Show
            
        End If
        
        Exit For
    Next Variable
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code doesn't consistently use fully-qualified Range references, so it's more difficult for us (and you!) to follow what it's doing, and also less robust than it could be.  *Every single* range reference should include an explicit worksheet reference (ie. never rely on the implicit `ActiveSheet`)  For review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: FYI you have `If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then` followed by `ElseIf ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then` which I'm pretty sure is not going to behave as you might expect.

Comment: Tim Williams - I am completely self-taught so yes, I'm sure someone with better knowledge than me could make it more robust. I have just really begun learning this stuff. Like I don't even know what a fully qualified range is lol. I'll read what you linked to. I'll see if I can find something else that will work instead, I guess for your second comment.

Comment: A qualified Range reference is one which doesn't depend on an implicit worksheet such as `ActiveSheet`.  So you should always be doing something like Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet"): ws.Range("A1").Value = "OK"`  Here `ws` is the explicit worksheet qualifier.

Comment: Well based upon how I wrote my code the active sheet is where all this code is going on as it is a search program displaying the results of 1 of 3 worksheets they selected during the start of the search so I couldn't say the code is specific to one worksheet or even 1 table because it could be for any of 3. I even had to find a code just to identify what table name they are working with on that particular sheet so the code could run dynamically. Am I doing it all wrong then?

Comment: Not "all wrong"  - it's just a standard recommendation here to avoid use of the implicit `ActiveSheet` (or even `ActiveWorkbook`)  It may all work fine up to a point, but then for example you change how your code gets triggered, and it starts failing in ways you might not notice.

Comment: I agree with that. I already figured out a consistent trigger already. That was the first thing I did. The makeup of this is currently in a test setup so I don't mess up the data, but the trigger will always remain the same.

Comment: Figured it out no and it works well.